# UIScrollView and still the keyboard hides the text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have uiscrollview, 2 textviewfields and I read all the posts about keyboard hiding textview and tried many methods, but still it hides it.

My code is like this:
ViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *campaignTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *campaignDescription;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property UITextView *activeTextView;
```

ViewController.m

```
@synthesize campaignTitle;
@synthesize campaignDescription;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize activeTextView;

#define SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_HEIGHT 460
#define SCROLLVIEW_CONTENT_WIDTH  320

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y+self.view.frame.size.height+50);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.text = @"";
    self.activeTextView = textView;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
     self.activeTextView = nil;
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextView.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeTextView.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-15));
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender
{
    [self.activeTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

There is delegation from the scroll view and campaignTitle, campaignDescription.

What is wrong? why the keyboard still hiding the bottom uitextview? The extra code that you may see is to support Return button in UITextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your UITextFields are actually inside of your UIScrollView inside your storyboard and not accidentally placed on the UIView below it.

setContentOffset should do SOMETHING, even if it is not the intended effect.  Since it seems to be doing nothing, I'd suspect that either your UITextFields are not subviews of it or your UIScrollView is not wired up in interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

Or use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](http://icodetricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/uitextfields-and-keyboard-issues/).
It is working great, and is very easy to setup:

1. Add a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib
2. Set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView (still
   in the xib, via the identity inspector)
3. Place all your controls within that scrollview

It also automatically hooks up "Next" buttons on the keyboard to switch through the text fields.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Seems somewhat backwards that iOS doesn't take care of this on it's own.